# Change playback speed in exoplayer

Tags: exoplayer2.x

I am trying to add a button from which I can slow down the playback speed. The code looks like this:

```
fun setupButtons(view: View){
        buttonContainer = view.findViewById(R.id.button_container)
        slowPlayButton = view.findViewById(R.id.slow_button)
        slowPlayButton.setOnClickListener({
            if (!isSlowPlaying) {
                player.setPlaybackSpeed(0.03f)
            } else {
                player.setPlaybackSpeed(1.0f)
            }
            isSlowPlaying = !isSlowPlaying
        })
    }
```

I have verified with debugger that `player.setPlaybackSpeed(0.03f)` is called, but the speed of the video is not changed.

If I instead set the playback speed when I set up the player, it is playing slowly.

```
private fun createAndShowVideo(baseFile: String) {
        val videoFile = baseFile + ".mp4"
        val mediaItem: MediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(videoFile.toUri())
        player.setMediaItem(mediaItem);
        player.prepare();
        player.addListener(this)
        player.setPlaybackSpeed(0.03f)
    }
```

What do I need to do to make the button call take effect?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution seems to be to override the array`exo_playback_speeds` in an `xml` called `arrays.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <string-array translatable="false" name="exo_playback_speeds">
        <item>0.025x</item>
        <item>0.1x</item>
        <item>0.2x</item>
        <item>0.4x</item>
        <item>0.8x</item>
        <item>@string/exo_controls_playback_speed_normal</item>
        <item>1.25x</item>
        <item>1.5x</item>
        <item>2x</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Comment: Doesn't work anymore since ExoPlayer 2.17.0